# Odd behaviour of pcolormesh with coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot a color mesh using matplotlib's `pcolormesh` function. However, it gives different results depending on whether I specify coordinates or not.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(9)
x = np.arange(10)
z = np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 10))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.pcolormesh(x, x, z)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.pcolormesh(z)
```

I expect the two calls to produce the same image but end up with the following plot. For example, the top-right corners of the plots differ.

[image: comparison]

Comment: Also note that the left plot has 9x9 rectangles and the right one 10x10

Comment: `pcolormesh` fills space (or cell) between the points defined by `x` and `y` lists, therefore the number of intervals less than the number of points. Try to set `x=np.arange(11)` and compare subplots. Read this doc: http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From help(pcolor)

```
...
Ideally the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of C;
if the dimensions are the same, then the last row and column of C will be ignored. ...
```

The left plot you are getting is a zoom in into the right one with top row and rightmost column removed.